# Efficient Dictionary Searching?

Tags: python, search, optimization, dictionary

I had a quick question about efficiency of searching through **large** dictionaries in Python. I am reading a large comma-separated file and getting a key and value from each line.  If my key is already in the dictionary, I'm adding the value to the value listed in the dictionary, if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary, I simply add the value.  Previously I was using this:

```
if key in data_dict.keys():
    add values
else:
    data_dict[key] = value
```

This starts pretty fast, but as the dictionary grows it becomes slower and slower, to the point where I can't use it at all.  I changed the way I search for the key in the dictionary to this:

```
try:
    # This will fail if key not present
    data_dict[keyStr] = input_data[keyStr] + load_val
except:
    data_dict[keyStr] = load_val
```

This is infinitely faster, and can read / write over 350,000 lines of code in 3 seconds.

My question was why does the `if key in data_dict.keys():` command take sooo much longer than the call to `try: data_dict[keyStr]`?  And why wouldn't Python utilize the `try` statement when searching for a key in a dictionary?

Comment: In general, you don't want to catch _all_ exceptions, but only the one you 'expect' and will handle when it is found. Here, e.g., use: `except KeyError: ...`

Comment: Your example code is confusing. In the first snippet you're checking for the `key` being in `data_dict`, but in the second the only thing that would give you a `KeyError` exception would be if the `key` wasn't in `input_data`. This makes it difficult to provide a complete answer...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The problem is that for every test you're generating a new list of keys with `.keys()`. As the list of keys gets longer, the time required goes up. Also [as noted by dckrooney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19103936/5987), the search for the key becomes linear instead of taking advantage of the hash-table structure of the dictionary.

Replace with:

```
if key in data_dict:
```

Comment: Hooray for also adding the most appropriate way to do it!

Comment: Ahh ok great.  I knew that .keys() regenerated the list of keys so I figured that was the issue, but I didn't know that you could just do "if key in dict:".  Thanks for the help.

Comment: *`for every test you're generating a new list of keys with .keys()`* So `key()` function is called every time **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, it's only called once per `if` but I assumed the `if` was called many times.

Comment: @MarkRansom but suppose if it called in for as `for k in d.keys()` that time also function will be called once Am I correct?

Comment: Yes I believe you are correct.  Here is some python code I used to test this.
>>> b = {}

>>> b[1] = 0

>>> c = 0

>>> b

{1: 0}
>>> for k in b.keys():
...     b[c] = 1
...     c = c+1
>>> b
{0: 1, 1: 0}

This code is adding a new key to the dictionary (b) everytime it loops through 'b.keys()'.  If it called b.keys() multiple times, this loop would never end because it is adding a new key for every loop.  However, it ends after 1 iteration, so it only makes 1 call.  Can someone confirm this?

Comment: @Brumdog22, yes I duplicated your results: http://ideone.com/imxdbe which is as I would expect, since `keys()` generates a list and the `for` loop is just going through that list. However things change in Python 3, `keys()` returns a generator and it won't allow you to change the dictionary inside the loop: http://ideone.com/wDfRLn

Answer (score 10):

`data_dict.keys()` returns an *unsorted* list of keys in the dictionary. Thus each time you check to see if a given key is in the dictionary, you're doing a linear search across the list of keys (an O(n) operation). The longer your list, the longer it takes to search for a given key.

Contrast this to `data_dict[keyStr]`. This performs a hash lookup, which is an O(1) operation.  It doesn't (directly) depend on the number of keys in the dictionary; even as you add more keys, the time to check if a given key is in the dictionary stays constant.

Answer (score 7):

You can also simply use

```
if key in data_dict:
```

instead of

```
 if key in data_dict.keys():
```

As mentioned, the first is a direct hash lookup - the intended offset is computed directly, and then checked - it is roughly O(1), whereas the check of keys is a linear search, which is O(n).

```
In [258]: data_dict = dict([(x, x) for x in range(100000)])

In [259]: %timeit 999999 in data_dict.keys()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.47 ms per loop

In [260]: %timeit 999999 in data_dict
10000000 loops, best of 3: 49.3 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

As several others have noted, the problem lies in the fact that `key in data_dict.keys()` uses the unordered ***`list`*** returned from the `keys()` method (in Python 2.x), which takes [linear time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time#Linear_time) ***O(n)*** to search through, meaning that the running time increases linearly with the dictionary's size, plus generating the list of keys itself will take longer and longer as the size goes up.

On the other hand, `key in data_dict` only requires constant time ***O(1)***, on average, to perform a search regardless of the size of the dictionary because internally it does a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) look-up. In addition, this hash table already exists since its part of the internal representation of dictionaries, and therefore doesn't have to be generated before using it.

Python doesn't do this automatically because the `in` operator only knows the type of its two operands, not their sources, so it can't automatically optimize the first case where all it sees is the key and a list.

However, in this case the issue of search speed can probably be avoided altogether by storing the data in a specialized version of a dictionary called a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) found in the built-in `collections` module. Here's how your code might look if you used one:

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_data = defaultdict(float)  # (guessing factory type)
...
data_dict[keyStr] = input_data[keyStr] + load_val
```

When there's no preexisting entry for `input_data[keyStr]` one will be generated automatically with a default value (`0.0` for `float` in this example). As you can see, the code is shorter and very likely faster, all without the need for any `if` tests or exception handling.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer the question, but rather avoids it. Try using `collections.defaultdict`. You won't need the `if/else` or `try/except` .

```
from collections import defaultdict

data_dict = defaultdict(list)
for keyStr, load_val in data:
    data_dict[keyStr].append(load_val)
```

Comment: alternatively - `data_dict[keyStr] = input_data.get(keyStr, [load_val])`

Answer (score 3):

This is because `data_dict.keys()` returns a *list* containing the keys in the dictionary (at least in Python 2.x). Which, in order to find if a key is in the list, requires a linear search.

Whereas, trying to access an element of the dict directly takes advantage of the awesome properties of dictionaries so the access is almost instantaneous.

Comment: In python3 `data_dict.keys()` returns iterator.

Comment: @defuz Did not know that, I still use mainly Python 2.7. Updated answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Back in the old days we used `setdefault`:

```
data_dict.setdefault(keyStr, []).append(load_val)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something akin to the try function that should help you:
[`dict.get(key, default)`](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#dictionary-get-method)

```
data_dict[keyStr] = data_dict.get(keyStr, '') + load_val
```

Answer (score 1):

As an extra analysis, I did a simple performance test to see how try/except method mentioned in the question compares with the proposed solution of using "if key in data_dict" instead of "if key in data_dict.keys()" (I am using Python 3.7):

```
    import timeit

    k = '84782005' # this keys exists in the dictionary
    def t1():
        if k in data_dict:
            pass
    def t2():
        if k in data_dict.keys():
            pass
    def t3():
        try:
            a = data_dict[k]
        except:
            pass

    print(timeit.timeit(t1,number= 100000))
    print(timeit.timeit(t2,number= 100000))
    print(timeit.timeit(t3,number= 100000))

    >> 0.01741484600097465
    >> 0.025949209000827977
    >> 0.017266065000512754
```

For the key that already exists in the dictionary, the search time seems to be the same for try/except and offered solution. However, if the key does not exist:

```
    k = '8' # this keys does NOT exist in the dictionary
    def t1():
        if k in data_dict:
            pass
    def t2():
        if k in data_dict.keys():
            pass
    def t3():
        try:
            a = data_dict[k]
        except:
            pass

    print(timeit.timeit(t1,number= 100000))
    print(timeit.timeit(t2,number= 100000))
    print(timeit.timeit(t3,number= 100000))

    >> 0.014406295998924179
    >> 0.0236777299996902
    >> 0.035819852999338764
```

The exception seems to take much more time than even using '.keys()'! So, I second the solution proposed by Mark.