# Why searching in dict.keys() is faster than dict.values()?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I was wondering why the speed of `dict.keys()` is much higher than `dict.values()` if there is a dictionary with millions of keys and values?

I was handling a file with millions of entries and searching in `dict.values()` was taking a huge amount of time compared to `dict.keys()`.

Meaning:

```
if x not in dict.keys():
```

vs.

```
if x not in dict.values():
```

Comment: Essentially because a dict is optimised for key lookup. That is how one usually uses it: `my_dict[some_key]` is the normal usage, which means looking up the key in `my_dict` (and retrieving the corresponding value), so that is optimised.

Comment: FWIW, `x in dict.keys()` is the same as `x in dict`, which checks if the key exists in the dict. That's obviously a very fast operation…

Comment: Dictionary keys have to be hashable and as such the underlying implementation can build optimised search algorithms to find keys. Values are not necessarily hashable and therefore a search through values is probably linear

Comment: Maybe the answer here will help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103785/efficient-dictionary-searching

Comment: NB: while this is of course example code, avoid using Python keywords or built-ins like `dict` or `list` as variable names.